# Reg Access Query

Tags: ms-access

Look at the example below

```
   type      qty   total
   A         10    10
   A         5     15
   S         7      8
   A         12    20
   S         5     15
```

I want an access query which can find total ie if type is 'A' add it to total and if type is 'S' subtract from total.Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Iif function to invert rows of type S, such as:

```
SELECT Sum(IIf([type]="S",-[total],[total])) AS subtotal
FROM table;
```

Alternatively in the query view, you can do this by adding a new field as:

```
subtotal: IIf([type]="S",-[total],[total])
```

Then activating the Totals icon in the toolbar, and choosing Sum as the value for the Totals.

Comment: Not sure whether you've interpreted 'total' correctly i.e. do they mean their column named 'total' or do they want to total (SUM)? I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT T1.type, T1.qty, T1.total, T1.total + T1.qty AS subtotal
  FROM MyTable AS T1
 WHERE T1.type = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT T1.type, T1.qty, T1.total, T1.total - T1.qty AS subtotal
  FROM MyTable AS T1
 WHERE T1.type = 'S';
```

or possibly this:

```
SELECT T1.type, T1.qty, T1.total, 
       T1.total + SWITCH(
                         T1.type = 'A', T1.qty, 
                         T1.type = 'S', 0 - T1.qty,
                         TRUE, NULL
                        ) AS subtotal
  FROM MyTable AS T1;
```

based on what you find easier to read, how you want to handle rows where is neither 'A' nor 'S', and which one performs best (in that order, IMO).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IIF(Type = 'A',total + qty,total - qty) as newTotal from table1
```